# elasticsearch 1.4.4 error using script filter with script_file

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch 1.4.4, I have this script -

```
doc[field].date.getMinuteOfDay() >= gte && doc[field].date.getMinuteOfDay() <= lte
```

Stored here - **config/script/minuteOfDayRange.groovy**

I run this query:

```
POST test_index/_search
{
  "filter": {
    "script": {
      "script_file": "minuteOfDayRange",
      "params": {
        "field": "start_time",
        "gte": 0,
        "lte": 1439
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

and get an error.  Here is part of the error (it's really big so I tried to show only the parts that looked the most helpful):

**"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;......nested: QueryParsingException[[test_index] [script] filter does not support [script_file]];......**

It sounds like this part of the error with **[script] filter does not support [script_file]** is saying script filters don't work with **script_file**.  Is that correct?  I've used **script_file** to generate terms with success on this same index.  Previous to updating to 1.4.4 this same filter worked using dynamic scripts, but I am now using the **script_file** method since updating to 1.4.4.  Is it possible for me to use a script filter in a file, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by changing **script_file** to just **script** in the query.

I found a similar issue on github that was a clue to try this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10007